# Print from Structures

Tags: c#, printing, structure

```
    using System;
 enum AccountState
        {
            New,
            Active,
            underAudut,
            Frozen,
            Closed
        } ; 
  struct Account
        {
            public AccountState State;
            public string Name;
            public string Adress;
            public int AccountNumber;
            public int Balance;
            public int Overdraft;
        } ;
    class BankProgram
    {
        public void PrintAccount(Account a)
        { Console.WriteLine("Name: " + a.Name);
          Console.WriteLine("Address: " + a.Adress);
          Console.WriteLine("Balance: " + a.Balance); }
        public static void Main()
        {
            Account RobsAccount;
            RobsAccount.State = AccountState.Active;
            RobsAccount.Name = "Rob Miles";
            RobsAccount.Adress = "His house";
            RobsAccount.AccountNumber = 1234;
            RobsAccount.Balance = 0;
            RobsAccount.Overdraft = -1000;
            Console.WriteLine("Name is : " + RobsAccount.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Balance is : " + RobsAccount.Balance);
            PrintAccount(Account RobsAccount);
        }
 }
```

hallo. i want to print the information from this command PrintAccount(Account RobsAccount);   but the compiler says 1) ) expected  (line 41)
                                      2) Invalid expression term ')'  (line 41)
                                      3) ; expected   (line 41)
line 41 is this command --> PrintAccount(Account RobsAccount);
Im working in C#

Comment: (Account RobsAccount) --> (RobsAccount)

Comment: it says Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'BankProgram.PrintAccount(Account)' 41 13 
...

Comment: Do you understand that most programming languages have a very strict syntax? Do you understand you need to balance your parentheses and accolades (i.e. one `{` needs one `}`)?  Did you try understanding the errors the compiler shows you?

Comment: i do :( but i dont think i have this kind of problem..

Answer (score 0):

When you *declare* a method, you do that in the form of:

```
[Modifiers] Return-Type-Or-Void Method-Name([Parameter-Type Parameter-Name[, Parameter-Type2 Parameter-Name2[, ...]]])
```

In your case:

```
Modifiers Return-Type-Or-Void Method-Name  Parameter-Type Parameter-Name
======    ====                ============ =======        =
public    void                PrintAccount(Account        a)
```

When you *call* a method, you do that in the form of:

```
[ResultVariable = ] Method-Name([Argument[, Argument2[, ...]]])
```

With your code:

```
PrintAccount(Account RobsAccount);
```

You're trying to call the method `PrintAccount`. The method declaration already has the type specified, so when calling it, you don't have to do that again:

```
PrintAccount(RobsAccount);
```

As for your second error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'BankProgram.PrintAccount

That text [occurs 32000 times on Stack Overflow](https://www.google.com/search?q=An+object+reference+is+required+for+the+non-static+field%2C+method%2C+or+property+site:stackoverflow.com), so I'm sure you can find a solution to that.

Comment: hallo and thanx for replying.. i did this before and i got this thing
Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'BankProgram.PrintAccount(Account)' 42 13

Comment: @user3217800 Erm no. You're missing the point. I'll make it simple: `foreach (result on Google) { read answer; } if (no solution found in all these 32000+ results) { ask question }`.